# how to get lastest message_id with python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want telegram bot  to  get the lastest message_id in a telegram group with python-telegram-bot?can you shou me  a example?
 `import telegram`

Comment: `update.message.message_id`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

So I have a working project for deleting forwarded messages, based on event_handler i.e. If any user sends text message to group, If its forwarded, then I delete it.

you can get that message_id via: update.message.message_id

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

TOKEN = "Enter your token here"

def echo(bot, update):
    if update.message.from_user.id not in get_admin_ids(bot, update.message.chat_id):
        bot.delete_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, message_id = update.message.message_id)
echo_handler=MessageHandler(Filters.forwarded, echo)


def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(echo_handler)
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```